# Sending 1-N data from Postman (or HTML file) to a Jersey Service

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I wanna write a Jersey service to get the following data:

- NAME, PHONE_AREA, PHONE_NUMBER
- NAME, PHONE_AREA, PHONE_NUMBER, PHONE_AREA, PHONE_NUMBER, PHONE_AREA, PHONE_NUMBER
- NAME, PHONE_AREA, PHONE_NUMBER, PHONE_AREA, PHONE_NUMBER)

As you can see (1) NAME x (1..*) PHONE(S) ( NAME, (PHONE_AREA, PHONE_NUMBER)+ )

1. How can I send those (varying) data from Postman (or even from a HTML file) to my service???

```
@POST @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FROM_URLENCODED)
public Response insert(MultivaluedMap<String, String> formParams) { ... }
```

2. How to get the phone(s) from the above???

```
@POST @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FROM_URLENCODED)
public Response insert(@FormParam("name") String name, **???**) { ... }
```

3. What type(s)/parameter(s) should I use in the above???